# How can I be sure of the file encoding?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, file-encodings

I have a PHP file that I created with VIM, but I'm not sure which is its encoding.

When I use the terminal and check the encoding with the command `file -bi foo` (My operating system is Ubuntu 11.04) it gives me the next result:

`text/html; charset=us-ascii`

But, when I open the file with gedit it says its encoding is UTF-8.

Which one is correct? I want the file to be encoded in UTF-8.

My guess is that there's no BOM in the file and that the command `file -bi` reads the file and doesn't find any UTF-8 characters, so it assumes that it's ascii, but in reality it's encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: What non-ASCII characters are in your file?

Comment: there is a good solution to use Microsoft visual studio code described in https://askubuntu.com/a/681803

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Well, first of all, note that ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so if your file contains only ASCII characters, it's correct to say that it's encoded in ASCII *and* it's correct to say that it's encoded in UTF-8.

That being said, `file` typically only examines a short segment at the beginning of the file to determine its type, so it might be declaring it us-ascii if there are non-ASCII characters but they are beyond the initial segment of the file. On the other hand, gedit might say that the file is UTF-8 even if it's ASCII because UTF-8 is gedit's preferred character encoding and it intends to save the file with UTF-8 if you were to add any non-ASCII characters during your edit session. Again, if that's what gedit is saying, it wouldn't be wrong.

Now to your question:

1. Run this command:

   ```
   tr -d \\000-\\177 < your-file | wc -c
   ```

   If the output says "0", then the file contains only ASCII characters. It's in ASCII (and it's also valid UTF-8) End of story.
2. Run this command

   ```
   iconv -f utf-8 -t ucs-4 < your-file >/dev/null
   ```

   If you get an error, the file does not contain valid UTF-8 (or at least, some part of it is corrupted).

   If you get no error, the file is extremely likely to be UTF-8. That's because UTF-8 has properties that make it very hard to mistake typical text in any other commonly used character encoding for valid UTF-8.

Comment: The first command returned 0, and the second command didn't return an error, so we can say it's UTF-8. Thanks!

Comment: it is giving me 1120 , what does this mean?

Comment: *What* is giving you 1120? The `wc`? If so then I guess you have 1120 non-ASCII bytes in the file.

Comment: Using `tr -d` is a very nice solution, since it allows for recognization of EBCDIC as well using `tr -d \\100-\\377`. Neither `file` nor `chardet` can do EBCDIC properly!

Comment: The first command returned 3 and the second nothing. :)

Answer (score 75):

```
$ file --mime my.txt 
my.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: I find it important to note that, like @Celada has already mentioned, `file` cannot *grant* that it's detection is 100% correct.

Answer (score 30):

(on Linux)

```
$ chardet <filename>
```

it also delivers the confidence level [0-1] of the output.

Comment: `chardet` seems to be a Python wrapper around `uchardet`, the "Universal" character encoding detector. `uchardet` is available on macos via Homebrew, although it doesn't give a confidence level.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Celada answer and the @Arthur Zennig, I have created this simple script:

```
#/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: utf8-check filename"
  exit 1
fi

chardet $1
countchars="$(tr -d \\000-\\177 < $1 | wc -c)"
if [ $countchars -eq 0 ]
then
 echo "Ascii";
 exit 0
fi

{
  iconv -f utf-8 -t ucs-4 < $1 >/dev/null
  echo "UTF-8"
} || {
  echo "not UTF-8 or corrupted"
}
```