# Travis missing encoding when uploading to S3 bucket

Tags: encoding, amazon-s3, travis-ci

I am uploading some .js files to an s3 bucket through Travis, one of the files has the following regex:

```
/(^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]+)/
```

The Travis .yml file is super simple:

```
- provider: s3
  access_key_id: THEKEY
  secret_access_key:
    secure: THESECUREDKEY
  bucket: my-bucket
  local-dir: build
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    branch: master
  acl: public_read
```

Nothing strange there, but after doing the upload, I am getting the following result inside the .js containing that regex (instead of the regex that I supplied):

```
/(^[a-zA-ZÃ Ã¡Ã¢Ã¤Ã£Ã¥Ä…ÄÄ‡Ä™Ã¨Ã©ÃªÃ«Ä—Ä¯Ã¬Ã­Ã®Ã¯Å‚Å„Ã²Ã³Ã´Ã¶ÃµÃ¸Ã¹ÃºÃ»Ã¼Å³Å«Ã¿Ã½Å¼ÅºÃ±Ã§ÄÅ¡Å¾Ã€ÃÃ‚Ã„ÃƒÃ…Ä„Ä†ÄŒÄ–Ä˜ÃˆÃ‰ÃŠÃ‹ÃŒÃÃŽÃÄ®ÅÅƒÃ’Ã“Ã”Ã–Ã•Ã˜Ã™ÃšÃ›ÃœÅ²ÅªÅ¸ÃÅ»Å¹Ã‘ÃŸÃ‡Å’Ã†ÄŒÅ Å½âˆ‚Ã° ,.'-]+)$/
```

As you can see, I missed most of the characters.

Is there a way to set the encoding to Travis when doing an upload to an s3 bucket?
Am I missing something else?

Comment: Is your file properly encoded ? use one of the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018967/how-can-i-be-sure-of-the-file-encoding) to ensure that. 

Does the proper metadata have been set ? (You should find a Content-Type entry in the metadata section of your file properties in AWS console)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing encoding problems. When this occurs your should check if anything between the start and the endpoint missing the encoding information for your file.

You have only Travis >> AWS, so its pretty easy.
Try setting [content-encoding](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3#Setting-Content-Encoding-header) to true

Comment: As @rolebi sad, also check file encondig if you are not sure about it.

Comment: setting `detect_encoding` to `true` didn't work for me

Comment: can you provide a sample branch with this part of your code? I'll try to figure out whats happen here