# MySQL 5.7.26 does not accept \N for nullable int column using Load Data Infile

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mysql-5.7

MySQL does not accept the \N value as null when I'm sure I've used it in the past for the same purpose.

Steps:

`CREATE TABLE t (i INT NULL, name varchar(50));`

Create a file called `test.txt` with tab separated fields:

```
1   John
\N  Jim
```

In MySQL:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.txt'
INTO TABLE t
Fields terminated BY "\t"
Escaped by ''
Lines terminated BY "\r\n";
```

Error:

`ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '\N' for column 'i' at row 2`

Comment: `'\N'` to me looks like a string. don't you want to use `NULL`

Comment: This might be a formatting problem of your text file. use utf-8 with an editor like notepad++, not windows notepad.

Comment: @FalcoGer I don't think encoding is the problem. I've just tested using a file created on Ubuntu using vi and I get the same error. The file is UTF-8 according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11021413/318807)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have done this:

```
LOAD DATA infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.txt'
INTO TABLE t
fields terminated BY "\t"
Escaped by '\\'
lines terminated BY "\r\n";
```