# PHP create a CSV file with Windows-1252 encoding

Tags: php, encoding, export-to-csv, windows-1252

I want to generate and save a CSV file with "Windows-1252" encoding.

My base code :

```php
$filename = 'path/to/file.csv';
$file = fopen($filename, 'w');
$datas[] = [
    "data 1",
    "data 2",
    "data 3",
    // ...
];
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    fputcsv($file, $data, ';');
}
fclose($file);
```

I tried to add some header :

```php
$options = [
    'http'=> [
        'header'=>
            "Content-Encoding: Windows-1252\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: text/csv; charset=Windows-1252\r\n"
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$file = fopen($tmpFile, 'w', false, $context);
```

And convert each lines before calling fputcsv() :

```php
foreach ($datas as $key => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $line) {
                // I tried this :
        $datas[$key] = iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $line);
                // and this :
        $datas[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'Windows-1252');
    }
    fputcsv($file, $datas, ';');
}
```

But without success :

```bash
$ file --mime-encoding *
file.csv:                 utf-8
```

What else should I do ?

Many thanks.

Comment: _"I tried to add some header :"_ - absolutely pointless; you are writing to a file, there is no HTTP involved in that part.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't change anything anyway. But thx.

Comment: _"But without success :"_ - that test result must not necessarily mean much, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11021413/1427878 (Windows-1252 characters below code point 127 are the same as in ASCII / UTF-8)

Comment: I have a file properly encoded for my needs. Notepad++ open it as ANSI, the command "file --mime-encoding" give me "unknown-8bit". My generated file give me UTF-8 in both cases.

Comment: I would open both in a hex editor, and see what difference you can spot (ideally you'd use the same data in the one you are dynamically creating, so it's easier to compare.) Also check the very beginning of your files for stuff like BOMs.

Comment: I can't compare two files with the same data. But I finally found a solution, I'll explain below. Many many thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution, by abandoning `fputcsv()` and replacing it with a `fwrite()` of my line after having `mb_convert_encoding()` it in "Windows-1252".

It's not as pretty, but it works :)